# function.arguments question

Tags: javascript

Please help me to understand following code:

Add method called 'later' to all objects. This method is used to call other method in future using `setTimeout`.

```
Object.prototype.later = function (msec, method) {
    // save 'this' as 'that' so we can use 'this' in inner function
    var that = this;
    // I cannot understand: what [2] means 
    // args will be ['Make is']. How?
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments, [2]);

    if (typeof method === 'string') {
        method = that[method];
    }
    // now use setTimeout to call method in future
    setTimeout(function () { method.apply(that, args); }, msec);
    return that;
}

// example of using later method
var car = {};
car.make = 'Ford';
car.show = function (message) {
    alert(message + ' ' + this.make);
}
car.later(1000, 'show', 'Make is');
```

So, when we call `car.later`, the third parameter is passed and will be used in **alert** function

Question is: how do we read third parameter "Make is"?

Answer (score 3):

The `apply` function expects as its second argument an array whose elements will be the arguments to the function being applied. So, this:

```
var args = Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments, [2]);
```

...says to call `Array`'s `slice` method on the `arguments` object passing in the argument `2` (i.e. populate the `arguments` object in the call to `slice` with one element, the number 2).

If the `arguments` object had its own `slice` method, then the above would be equivalent to this:

```
arguments.slice(2);
```

The `apply` trick is necessary because `arguments` is not really an instance of `Array` and does not have a `slice` method.

What this does is return a new array having all elements of `later`s `arguments` object from the third on. That's why it returns `['Make is']`.

If you actually just want the string that is the third element in `arguments`, then do this:

```
arguments[2];
```

Note also the existence of `call`, which is just like `apply` except that it allows you to pass a list of values to use to populate the `arguments` object, so that you don't have to wrap your argument in an array as you've done above:

```
var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
```

Comment: +1 for pointing me to the fact that arguments isn't a true array.

Comment: I really appreciate you answer! Your post made it clear for me. Now I wonder how I didn't understand that yesterday :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The "arguments" in Javascript is an array-like object of all the arguments passed into a function. In the case of your call to later:

```
car.later(1000, 'show', 'Make is');
```

The value of "arguments" will be [1000, 'show', 'Make is'], so the individual elements of the array are as follows: arguments[0] is 1000, arguments[1] is 'show', and arguments[2] is 'Make is'. Here is a page that explains some about optional arguments in JavaScript functions: http://www.openjs.com/articles/optional_function_arguments.php and here's a good one that goes into the arguments object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Functions#Using_the_arguments_object